# How to trigger github actions with dispatch using gh cli

Tags: github, github-api, github-actions

I have a action which has the following yaml in it:

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      BuildTarget:
        description: "Targets to rebuild. Set to all to rebuild everything."
        required: false
        default: ""
```

Which I can trigger with:

```
gh api /repos/:owner/:repo/actions/workflows/build_dev.yml/dispatches -F ref=":branch"
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to pass inputs into the action from the cli.

I have tried:

```
gh api /repos/:owner/:repo/actions/workflows/build_dev.yml/dispatches -F ref=":branch" -F BuildTarget=all
```

Which tells `"BuildTarget" is not a permitted key. (HTTP 422)`

and trying this:

```
gh api /repos/:owner/:repo/actions/workflows/build_dev.yml/dispatches -F ref=":branch" -F inputs='{ "BuildTarget": "all" }'
```

Gives me `For 'properties/inputs', "{ \"BuildTarget\": \"all\" }" is not an object. (HTTP 422)`

Any idea on how to call this api from the cli and pass in input properties to a workflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send the raw body directly using `--input -` to read from standard input :

```sh
gh api /repos/:owner/:repo/actions/workflows/build_dev.yml/dispatches \
   --input - <<< '{"ref":"master","inputs":{"BuildTarget":"all"}}'
```

Checkout [this documentation](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api)

Comment: docs link: 
```
https://docs.github.com/cn/rest/actions/workflows
https://docs.github.com/cn/rest/repos/repos#create-a-repository-dispatch-event
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have any `inputs` to pass in and are just running the workflow, you can use:

```bash
gh api /repos/joshjohanning-org/bash-testing/actions/workflows # get id
gh api -X POST /repos/joshjohanning-org/bash-testing/actions/workflows/19595110/dispatches -f ref='main'
```

Otherwise if you want inputs, use @Bertrand Martel's example in this post.

Or use [gh workflow run](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_workflow_run):

```bash
gh workflow run -R joshjohanning-org/bash-testing blank.yml 
echo '{"name":"scully", "greeting":"hello"}' | gh workflow run -R joshjohanning-org/bash-testing blank.yml --json
```

Comment: `gh workflow run` is the specific command to run workflows. It shields you from having to know the dispatches URL which could theoretically change.